# Fast Fourier transform in Erlang

Tags: erlang, fft

I am looking for an example of using FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) in Erlang. Can show me an example of code?

Comment: Number crunching is nothing Erlang is good at. You should probably use a C library though NIFs ("native implemented functions" - http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.9/erts-5.9/doc/html/erl_nif.html).

Comment: It's been a very long time since I did anything with it, but I recall that FFT was designed to do transforms in-place.  The input and output buffers are the same memory. (Correct me if I'm wrong!) This is an extremely useful property if you're working in embedded applications with tight memory constraints, but if you have a ton of memory (or are using Erlang and *can't* change values in a buffer) you can write a faster FT than FFT.  Of course, I'm going to agree with @Kay here and say that Erlang would be a terrible choice of languages for this work and it should be done through a port.

Comment: Just be warned that using NIF's may mess up erlang's schedular, which means that you may not get the performance you want in cases of heavy utilisation